# JFrame only refreshed when a method ends

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I'm developing a game using Netbeans, but now I am stuck.

Inside the main `JFrame` class, I have developed some methods, each of them have have many lines in which for example, the icons of components contained by the frame change. The issue is that I only see the changes at the same time once the method has finished it's execution, instead of watching them sequentially.

I know this because in one of my methods, for example, I use several threads to take some seconds between many `JLabel` icon changes, but the result is that after waiting the full amount of seconds of all the thread objects I use, all the changes are displayed exactly at the same time. I suppose that it must be a way of refreshing the frame before the methods end, but which one?

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: What @Andrew says is correct (and should be an answer rather than a comment, I think). If it doesn't make sense, please ask us for clarification, but also tell us more details about your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  It is a fine line, with these type of questions, as to whether that comment constitutes an answer, or whether the question should be closed as a 'duplicate that can be guessed from the title' - wait.. there's no category for that.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at SwingWorker. You sould do all computation in this thread and leave the EventDispatchThread free so it can refresh your UI.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html